# Difference between external and internal direct product?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the difference between external and internal direct product ?? I think both of them boil down to the same thing.

Comment: I just try my best to forget the distinction even exists because I think it's unnecessary

Comment: I convinced myself like this:  in an external direct product, the multiplication/operation works the way that it does *by construction*, whereas in internal you have a *pre-existing* operation that happens to let the original object be recovered from some subobjects/factors -- more like a decomposition or factorisation (vs. expansion), if you will.  Other than the connotation, they really are the same; $K=G \cross H$ (where $G,H$ are given) makes the product feel external, but any equation can of course be read from right to left, and $G \cross H = K$ (where you start with $K$) seems internal.

Comment: Need a small edit to your TEX command

Answer (score 10):

They are two different ways of looking at the same thing, but the definitions are basically equivalent.

> Every internal direct product $G$ is naturally isomorphic to the external direct product (of its direct factors).

and

> Every external direct product is naturally realized as an internal direct product.

The biggest distinction I've seen is that if $A,B \subset G $, and $A\times B \cong G$, we say $G$ is the internal direct product of $A$ and $B$. However, if $A,B$ are not subgroups of $G$ (rather, they are isomorphic to direct factors of $G$), we would say $G \cong A \times B$ is an external direct product.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a group with identity element $e$. Let $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of $G$ such that $H \cap K= \{e\}$. Then $H \times K \simeq H \oplus K$ where $H \times K$ is the internal direct product between $H$ and $K$ and $H \oplus K$ is the external direct product between $H$ and $K$. When $H$ and $K$ have nontrivial intersection this may not hold.

Comment: If $H, K$ as normal and has the trivial intersection, can we say that any element of $H$ is commute with any element of $K$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is is that in the internal direct product is between the subgroups of the same group $G$ but in the external direct product it can be made for any two groups in which they don't have any relation between them