# What does $AB$ called?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

In Artin's Algebra, I get this:

> If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a group $G$, then
>
> $$AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,\space\space b\in B\}$$
>
> We will call this *the product of the two subsets of the group*, though **in other contexts** the term product may stand for the set $A\times B$

**My question:** Is there any specific name of this set $AB$? If so, then what is it?

I know $A\times B$ is the product of the two sets(specially it is called *Cartesian Product*). But in group theory, $AB$ comes frequently, we can't just call it *product* too!

**Added:** I found $A\times B$ is also called [Direct product of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is referred to as the *set-theoretic* product.

Comment: @NickyHekster I googled set-theoretic product. all it was saying about Cartesian Product.... but my question is different.

Comment: But it is called *product*, you are not going to change that, as there is a product defined for the elements of the group. In my lectures I always used set-theoretic, to emphasize that $AB$ is merely a *set* and does not have to be a *subgroup*, although $A$ and $B$ can be subgroups.

Comment: In German text books it is referred as complex product.

Comment: Sometimes "Frobenius product" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a widely used term for that, but "Finite-dimensional Spaces" by W. Noll seem to call it member-wise product which should cause no confusion. That term ought not be misunderstood.

Another alternative is using the term "**non**-cartesian product". That way the reader will know that it's **not** the cartesian product at least.

Wikipedia is calling it "product of group subsets", but there's a risk of misunderstanding in such terminology. Wikipedia also uses the term "product of subsets", but the factors in cartesian product are also subsets. Your source seem to point out that in other contexts that term may refer to cartesian product.

Comment: Thanks, **non**-Cartesian product is a easy way discriminant with $A\times B$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no specific name of $AB$ other than *product of groups*.But the concept of $AB$ and $A \times B$ are not same.$A \times B$ is called *internal 
direct product* of $A$  and   $B$.$AB=A \times B$ if $A$ and $B$ are normal subgroups of $AB$ and $A \cap B=\phi$ so $AB \ne A \times B$ in general.

Comment: i don't why are you saying $A\times B$ and $AB$ could be equal ! $A\times B$ talks about pairs and $AB$ is not.

Comment: See the difference of Internet direct product and Externe direct product pod groups [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928524/difference-between-external-and-internal-direct-product)